# Is it possible to handle two or more shortcodes in a single page?

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode **[API-Module version="1"]** and another shortcode like **[API-Module version="2"]**

If i handle any one at a time in a single page it works perfectly. Yet my requirement needs both had to be visible in front end(UI) when handling two shortcodes. Is there any possibilities to do so ?

Constructor to add short-code:

```
function __construct() {
            add_shortcode('API-Module', array(&$this, 'handle_shortcode'));
        }
```

This part is used in handling short-code:

```
 function handle_shortcode($atts) { 
 $version_type = $atts['version'];
    ob_start(); 
    require_once "/front_end/view/api-list.php"; 
    $output_string=ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return $output_string;  
     }
```

Comment: There is no limit to the number of shortcode (even *same* shortcode) in a page. If it doesn't work there is a problem in the function that handle the shortcode. Post it to have chance of any help...

Comment: Post it in the **question**. And post (the relevant part) of api-list.php. This code -pratically- do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) on [`require_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php):

> The **require_once** statement is identical to [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and *if so, not include (require) it again*.

The second time your shortcode handler is run, the view/template will not be executed.
Hence no output.

Change
`require_once "/front_end/view/api-list.php";`
to
`require "/front_end/view/api-list.php";`
and you ought to be fine.